# Pass user to class with React Router Dom

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

New to react and having trouble passing the user over to a page. I was able to get it working with my Navbar component but from my limited knowledge I do not know how to get it working with a page. I am trying to use the `user.attributes.x` like I am doing in **Navbar** on line 38.

App.js:

```
import React from "react";
import { Auth, Hub } from "aws-amplify";
import { Authenticator, AmplifyTheme } from "aws-amplify-react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";

// Template Pages
import LandingPage from './pages/LandingPage';
// Pages

// Supporting Pages
import DocumentationPage from './pages/DocumentationPage';
import FeedbackPage from './pages/FeedbackPage';
// Util Pages
import Navbar from "./components/Navbar.js";
import ErrorPage from "./pages/ErrorPage.js";


const listener = (data) => {
  switch(data.payload.event) {
    case "signIn":
      console.log('A new auth event has happened: ' + data.payload.event)
      this.getUserData()
      break;
    case "signUp":
      console.log('A new auth event has happened: ' + data.payload.event)
      break;
    case 'signIn_failure':
      console.error('A new auth event has happened: ' + data.payload.event)
      break;
    case "signOut":
      console.log('A new auth event has happened: ' + data.payload.event)
      this.setState({ user: null })
      break;
    default:
      return;
   }
  }

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    user: null,
    userAttributes: null
  };

  federated = {
    saml_client_id: ''
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getUserData();
    Hub.listen('auth', listener);
  }

  getUserData = async () => {
     const user = await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser()
      user ? this.setState({ user }, () => this.getUserAttributes(this.state.user)) : this.setState({ user: null })
  }

  getUserAttributes = async authUserData => {
    const attributesArr = await Auth.userAttributes(authUserData)
    const attributesObj = await Auth.attributesToObject(attributesArr)
    this.setState({ userAttributes: attributesObj})
  }

  handleSignOut = async () => {
    await Auth.signOut()
      .then(data => console.log(data))
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }

  render() {
    const { user } = this.state;

    return !user ? <Authenticator signUpConfig={signUpConfig} theme={theme} /> : (
      <Router>
        <>
          {/* Navbar */}
          <Navbar user={user} handleSignOut={this.handleSignOut} listener={this.listener} />
          {/* Routes */}
          <div className="app-container">
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path="/" user={user} component={LandingPage}/>
              {/* Pages */}

              {/* Support */}
              <Route exact path="/docs" component={DocumentationPage}/>
              <Route exact path="/feedback" component={FeedbackPage}/>
              {/* 404/Error Page */}
              <Route component={ErrorPage}/>
            </Switch>
          </div>
        </>
      </Router>
    );
  } 
}

const theme = {
  ...AmplifyTheme,
  button: {
    ...AmplifyTheme.button, 
    backgroundColor: '#1565C0',
    color: '#FFFFFF'
  },
  navBar: {
    ...AmplifyTheme.navBar,
    backgroundColor: '#1565C0'
  },
  sectionHeader: {
    ...AmplifyTheme.sectionHeader,
    backgroundColor: '#1565C0'
  }
}; 

const signUpConfig = {
  hideAllDefaults: true,
  signUpFields: [
    {
      label: 'Email',
      key: 'email',
      required: true,
      displayOrder: 1,
      type: 'string',
    },
    {
      label: 'Password',
      key: 'password',
      required: true,
      displayOrder: 2,
      type: 'password',
    },
],
};

// const signInConfig = {

// };

export default App;
```

Navbar.js where it is currently working:

```
import React from "react";
import logo from "./sd-logo copy.PNG";
import SD from "./SDHighDef copy.jpg";

var stickyStyle = {
    // position: fixed,
    top: 0,
    width: 1268
}

const Navbar = ({ user, handleSignOut, listener }) => (
    <div className="uk-offcanvas-content">
      <div className="uk-section-default tm-section-texture">
        <div uk-sticky="media: 960" className="uk-navbar-container tm-navbar-container uk-navbar-transparent uk-section-default uk-sticky uk-sticky-fixed" style={stickyStyle}>
          <div className="uk-container uk-container-expand">
            <nav className="uk-navbar">
              <div className="uk-navbar-left">
                {/* Branding */}
                <a href="/" className="uk-navbar-item uk-logo router-link-exact-active uk-active">
                  <img src={logo} width="65" height="34" viewBox="0 0 28 34" ratio="1" className="uk-margin-small-right uk-svg" /> Test App
                </a>
              </div>

              <div className="uk-navbar-right">

                {/* Name and Company */}
                <div className="uk-navbar-item uk-link-reset">
                    <span className="uk-text-lowercase">{user.attributes.email} <canvas uk-icon="icon: chevron-down" width="20" height="20" className="uk-icon" hidden={true}></canvas></span>
                </div>
                <div uk-dropdown="animation: uk-animation-slide-top-small; duration: 1000">
                    <ul className="uk-nav uk-dropdown-nav">
                        <li><a href="https://www.office.com/" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" className="uk-text-muted">User:<br />{user.attributes.email}</a></li>
                        <li><a href="https://www.office.com/" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" className="uk-text-muted">Account:<br /> placeholder</a></li>
                        <li className="uk-nav-divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="https://www.office.com/" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer"><canvas uk-icon="icon: cog" width="20" height="20" className="uk-icon" hidden={true}></canvas> Profile</a></li>
                        <li className="uk-nav-divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="/" onClick={handleSignOut}><canvas uk-icon="icon: sign-out" width="20" height="20" className="uk-icon" hidden={true}></canvas> Sign Out</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                {/* Support , Support Center, Documentation, Training*/}
                <ul className="uk-navbar-nav uk-link-reset">
                    <div className="uk-nav-item">Support <canvas uk-icon="icon: chevron-down" width="20" height="20" className="uk-icon" hidden={true}></canvas></div>
                        <div uk-dropdown="animation: uk-animation-slide-top-small; duration: 1000">
                            <ul className="uk-nav uk-dropdown-nav">
                                <li><a href="/docs" rel="noopener noreferrer"><canvas uk-icon="icon: album" width="20" height="20" className="uk-icon" hidden={true}></canvas> Documentation</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/feedback"><canvas uk-icon="icon: commenting" width="20" height="20" className="uk-icon" hidden={true}></canvas> Feedback</a></li>
                                <li className="uk-nav-divider"></li>
                                <li className="uk-margin-top">
                      <img src={SD} width="250" height="100" viewBox="0 0 100 100" ratio="1" className="uk-margin-small-right uk-svg" />
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </nav>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    )

export default Navbar;
```

LandingPage.js where I am having the trouble:

```
import React from "react";
import { Storage, API, graphqlOperation, Logger  } from "aws-amplify";
import { createHistoryItem } from '../graphql/mutations';
import { getHistoryItem } from '../graphql/queries';
import * as queries from '../graphql/queries';
import noFiles from './noFiles.png';

const logger = new Logger('logger', 'INFO');

class LandingPage extends React.Component {

  state = {
    history: '',
    files: [],
    fileUrl: '',
    file: '',
    fileName: '',
    fileSize: '20 MB',
    classInput: 'Other',
    action: '',
    client: 'x',
    prefix: 'raw/clients/x/' + this.classInput + '/' 
  }

  componentDidMount = async () => {

    const userHistory = await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(queries.getHistoryItem, { owner: user.attributes.id }))
      .then(result => {
        logger.info(result);
        logger.info('Got users History with getHistoryItem in componentDidMount')
        this.setState({ history: userHistory })
      })
      .catch(err => {
        logger.error("Erroring getting users History Item with getHistoryItem in componentDidMount")
      })
    logger.info(userHistory)
    logger.info('Exiting componentDidMount')
  }

  // Function for getting correct local time
  addZero(i) {
    if (i < 10) {
      i = "0" + i;
    }
    return i;
  }

  render() {
    const { classInput } = this.state.classInput;

    return (
      <>
      <div>
        <div> 

        </div>
      </div> {/* End div to wrap everything */}
      </>
    )
  }
}

export default LandingPage;
```

The error I get is `./src/pages/LandingPage.js
  Line 40:  'user' is not defined  no-undef`.

How do I correctly pass the user over to LandingPage?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through Route you can pass like this way

```
           <Route
              exact
              path="/"
              render={props => <LandingPage user={"a user"} />}
            />
```

And you can get the user from Landing Page using **`this.props.user`**

Another way you can pass through **`Link`**, Link you can consider one menu item of your navbar, basically it generate  tag at back end. You need to import Link from react-router-dom

`import { Link } from "react-router-dom";`

```
<Link to={{ pathname: "/", state: { user: {"a user"} } }}>
          Home
        </Link>
```

And you can retrieve using **`this.props.location.state.user`**

Comment: it's saying ```this.props.user``` is undefined

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `component` as a function and add your custom props there, just remember to also add the original props from the Router:

```
<Route exact path="/" component={(routerProps) => <LandingPage user={user} {...routerProps} />}/>
```

The `user` prop will be accessible in `LandingPage` as any other prop.